# corona sdk pinch to zoom on image

Tags: lua, zooming, coronasdk, pinch

I have a problem implementing the pinch to zoom function. Basically I have a various range of pictures in my app and I need to implement the pinch to zoom just for some of them. I am new to LUA and I already saw the example they give you on the corona website. I need help implementing that code the way I need, can someone help me?

Comment: what code have you tried? what problems are you having?

Comment: http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/01/22/implementing-pinch-zoom-rotate/
I followed this tutorial, but since i'm not a pro, i find it hard to implent it into my code. My app only needs to zoom and navigate an image. I'd like some tips on how to implement it